# Render email HTML in a VueJS component without impacting the global styles

Tags: html, css, vue.js, iframe, vuejs2

I'm drafting a VueJS app which allows users to insert an email HTML template, do some processing and download the processed template afterwards.

I have two components and trying to render the HTML via the `HTMLViewer` component with `v-html` function as follows:

Home:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <mdb-container>
      <mdb-row>
        <mdb-col>
          <div class="form-group">
            <mdb-input
              type="textarea"
              label="Paste your HTML here:"
              outline
              :rows="25"
              v-model="emailTemplate"
            />
          </div>
        </mdb-col>
        <mdb-col>
          <HTMLViewer :emailTemplate="emailTemplate" />
        </mdb-col>
      </mdb-row>
      <mdb-row class="ml-1">
        <mdb-btn outline="default">Next</mdb-btn>
        <mdb-btn outline="danger" @click="clearEmailTemplate">Clear</mdb-btn>
      </mdb-row>
    </mdb-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbContainer, mdbRow, mdbCol, mdbInput, mdbBtn } from 'mdbvue';
import HTMLViewer from '../components/HTMLViewer';

export default {
  name: 'HomePage',
  components: {
    mdbContainer,
    mdbRow,
    mdbCol,
    mdbInput,
    mdbBtn,
    HTMLViewer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      emailTemplate: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clearEmailTemplate() {
      this.emailTemplate = null;
      this.iframeVisible = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

HTMLViewer:

```
<template>
    <div v-html="emailTemplate">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbContainer, mdbRow, mdbCol, mdbInput, mdbBtn } from 'mdbvue';

export default {
  name: 'HTMLViewer',
  components: {
    mdbContainer,
    mdbRow,
    mdbCol,
    mdbInput,
    mdbBtn
  },
  props:['emailTemplate'],
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

The problem I'm facing is the fact that the email template CSS styles overwrite the ones from the parent component (Home).

I tried to use iFrame which solves this issue but also creates a lot of different problems related to interacting with the HTML template, therefore I would like to avoid iframe as much as possible.

My question is - is there a good way to make sure the inserted email template HTML does not affect the global styles?

Comment: Where are the email styles? Are they in the mail template and get injected into the page via the `v-html` or are they separated?

Comment: They're in the email template and get injected into the page vie the v-html.

Comment: i used iframe also but it is hard to intercept links for example